# Why the first three breaklines can't be displayed?

Tags: html, css

Why the three br elements  can't be displayed  ?

```css
#content1{
  float:left;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
#content2{
  width:300px;
  height:700px;
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
  
   <div id="content1">
      <p>content1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="content2">
      <br/><br/><br/>
      <p>content2</p>
      <br/><br/><br/>
      <p>content2</p>
  </div>
```

From the html structure ,there are three breaklines before content2 and three breaklines after content2,
only the  second three breaklines can be displayed ,why the first three breaklines can be displayed?

[image]

In my opinion the result will be as following.

[image]

In my html div content1 and div content2 will be overlayed with each other,why the first three blank lines will be affected by floating div content1?

Let's add two more examples to show my confusion.

```css
#content1{
  float:left;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
#content2{
  width:300px;
  height:700px;
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
  
   <div id="content1">
      <p>content1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="content2">
      <p>haha</p>
      <br/><br/><br/>
      <p>content2</p>
      <br/><br/><br/>
      <p>content2</p>
  </div>
```

The displayed effect.
[image]

```css
#content1{
  float:left;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
#content2{
  width:300px;
  height:700px;
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
  
   <div id="content1">
      <p>content1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="content2">
      <br/><br/><br/>
      <p>content2</p>
      <br/><br/><br/>
      <p>content2</p>
  </div>
```

The displayed effect.
[image]

html3 is just more one line than htm4:

haha

.
In html3 the first blank lines can be displayed,why the first blank lines gone in html4?
What is the reseaon behind the phenomenon?What ate my first blank lines in html4?
Why html4 was not be parsed as the following image?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of afelixj, i got it.
We can add more white lines such as 12 
 in the html body to observe the appearance of css.

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
    #content1{
      float:left;
      width:300px;
      height:300px;
      border:1px solid red;
    }
    #content2{
      width:300px;
      height:700px;
      border:5px solid green;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div id="content1">
        <p>content1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content2">
        <p style="margin:0px;border: 2px dashed green;"></p>
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <p>content2</p>
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <p>content2</p>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Clear the second div `#content2`.

```css
#content1{
  float:left;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
#content2{
  width:300px;
  height:700px;
  border:1px solid green;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
 <div id="content1">
  <p>content1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="content2">
  <br/><br/><br/>
  <p>content2</p>
  <br/><br/><br/>
  <p>content2</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: first div is floated

Comment: In my html div content1 and div content2 will be overlayed with each other,why the first three blank lines will be affected by floating div content1?

Comment: not the first three line breaks, the whole second div is affected by floating div1

Answer (score 1):

I have added a dashed border for the new p tag. Check where it starts. The box model starts on top, but content  'haha' will be visible only after the floating box.

The top spacing is the margin of that p tag.

Similarly the line breaks are actually visible on top. Since line breaks don't have any visual content, we don't notice them in the output.

```css
#content1{
  float:left;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
#content2{
  width:300px;
  height:700px;
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
  
   <div id="content1">
      <p>content1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="content2">
      <p style="border: 2px dashed green;">haha</p>
      <br/><br/><br/>
      <p>content2</p>
      <br/><br/><br/>
      <p>content2</p>
  </div>
```